# aws-serverless-express connection error - EPIPE

Tags: node.js, express, serverless-framework

We have a NodeJS 10.16.3 Express API. We've recently switched from AWS Elastic Beanstalk/EC2 to Lambda / Serverless. Our DB is Postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.2.

It seemed all of a sudden I started getting this error on my local server when making requests from the client:

```
offline: ANY /dev/inventory/inventory (λ: app)
ERROR: aws-serverless-express connection error
{ Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:788:14) errno: 'EPIPE', code: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }
offline: (λ: app) RequestId: ckazracm0001emds69068drtu  Duration: 2.58 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms
```

I can't seem to find much on this issue and I'm hoping someone can help.

Notes:

- My local postgres is running
- My .env.json file is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Hopefully this will be helpful for others.

The error was due to exceeding the max cookie size of 4096 bytes in the application request headers. We solved it by stripping out erroneous cookies that were passed through some 3rd party services we were using, which has long encoded strings for cookie values.